# SVN Import: "Error: Could not open the requested SVN filesystem"

Tags: linux, svn, apache, tortoisesvn

I try to import my old project to new SVN server (svn + web_dav+apache), but however I get some weird error while importing with tortoiseSVN.

```
Adding: C:\tmp\carpirate\test  
Adding: C:\tmp\carpirate\test\crawlerTestSuite  
Adding: C:\tmp\carpirate\test\crawlerTestSuite\TestP2p.java  
Adding: C:\tmp\carpirate\test\crawlerTestSuite\TestMessageHandler.java  
Adding: C:\tmp\carpirate\test\crawlerTestSuite\TestGui.java  
Adding: C:\tmp\carpirate\test\crawlerTestSuite\TestListener.java  
Adding: C:\tmp\carpirate\test\crawlerTestSuite\TestServerConnection.java  
Adding: C:\tmp\carpirate\test\crawlerTestSuite\TestCollectorMind.java  
Error: Could not open the requested SVN filesystem
```

I checked read/write permissions from repository (tried to set all to 777), but nothing works. Neither commit do the job.

Do you have any clues, what I'm missing?

Comment: What commands did you run to setup the repository? To check out a working copy?

Comment: I set up repository with svnadmin create.
I can check out with tortoise, but not commit.
We use plesk to manage web sites, can it disturb svn connection in any way?

Comment: may be it is useful, in logs after couple of 201 for added files

[07/Feb/2010:14:57:14 +0100] "PROPFIND /carpirate/!svn/wrk/fbe63b77-bc79-c444-bfd1-6316b0c5e78e/.classpath HTTP/1.1" 500 634 "-" "SVN/1.6.3 (r38063)/TortoiseSVN-1.6.3.16613 neon/0.28.4"

Comment: please look into the error.log there should be more information about this server error (http-code 500)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved the problem, but the solution is a little bit messy and disappointing.

We moved repository parent to a path, with full read/write permissions for apache, authentication files were moved to apache configs, after all that it works.

I suspect it was matter to exclude plesk from webdav access.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in a Plesk world..

Solution: Disable custom error docs for your domain. To do so, log in to Plesk, navigate to the domain and uncheck the "Custom error documents" box in hosting settings.
Alternativ solution: Create a repo named error (or error_docs or whatever you find in the logs).
see : 
http://pnpq.blogspot.com/2011/11/apache-svn-could-not-open-requested-svn.html?showComment=1324510115093#c5273051064616678938

Answer (score 0):

Is this a problem of repo format (BDS  Berkeley DB or [FSFS](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.planning.html#svn.reposadmin.basics.backends.fsfs))?

If so, see [Subversion FAQ How do I convert my repository from using BDB to FSFS or from FSFS to BDB?](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#bdb-fsfs-convert)

Comment: See this thread for illustration: http://translate.google.fr/translate?js=y&prev=_t&hl=fr&ie=UTF-8&layout=1&eotf=1&u=http://forum.generation-nt.com/developpements/tortoisesvn-could-not-open-the-requested-svn-filesystem-166730/&sl=fr&tl=en

Comment: No, it should be abstracted trough webdav and apache.
Above all it is a brand new repository and I try to import clean data without any information about old repository.

Comment: @p4553d interesting. Let us know (by posting here an answer) if you find the root cause of that message.